Cuda unavailable in tmux but available normally
I use tmux version 3.0a
The details of my GPU are :
NVIDIA-SMI 460.91.03    Driver Version: 460.91.03    CUDA Version: 11.2
I've been trying to run yolo v6 code from ultralytics to train the yolo v6 model on the COCO dataset in vscode:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import torch


print(torch.cuda.is_available()) 
device=torch.device('cuda:2')

model = YOLO('yolov6n.yaml').to(device)

model.info()
 
model.train(data='coco.yaml', epochs=5, imgsz=640)
metrics = model.val()  

results = model('/home/objectdetection/sfolder/yolo6/bus.jpg')

Here, when I tried to run this on tmux, I'm getting the following error:-
RuntimeError: The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 11020). Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version of the CUDA driver.
But when I'm running it without tmux, then it is running perfectly fine on my GPU
Why is this happening?
